# Redshift WLM: "final queue may not contain User Groups or Query Groups"

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to update the WLM configuration for my Redshift cluster, but I am unable to make changes and save them due to the following message displayed:

> The following problems must be corrected before you can save this workload configuration:
>
> The final queue may not contain User Groups or Query Groups.

Now, the obvious solution is to just create a new queue with no user group specified and give it the remaining amount of memory so that it all adds up to 100%. That's annoying because adding a new queue requires cluster reboot, but that's not the reason I'm asking this question.

My main question is where is this need for a new "non-user" queue explained? This is definitely a change because previously, I had four queues, each with an assigned user group, and their collective memory allocation was 87%. It didn't add up to 100%, and supposedly the rest was dynamically managed by redshift.

Now, I have no problem creating this new queue, but I would really like to see an explicit explanation of what it does/what its affects are before I do it. I didn't see an update on their official blog, I don't see this mentioned in the docs, or the doc updates (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/document-history.html, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/doc-history.html)   This is blocking me from making other desired changes to the existing queues.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this statement of yours:

> previously, I had four queues, each with an assigned user group

However, it is easy to guess why Redshift requires a default queue (i.e. one which doesn't have any User or Query groups) as the last one. Let's say you have four queues, each of which has a different User group, say, UG1, UG2, UG3 and UG4. Now, a User from another User group, say UG5, queries Redshift. Which queue does it get routed to? A default queue helps in such a case.

You might counter-argue that Redshift can use the remaining 13% memory. What if 100 concurrent queries came from UG5. Redshift doesn't have any configuration of how you'd like the 13% memory to be allocated to these queries. If it manages the memory on its own, the performance of your cluster would be unpredictable.

But yeah, I agree that the Redshift documentation lacks clarity on this. The closest I could find was [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-defining-query-queues.html). Though, it doesn't say that the default queue can't have any User or Query groups.

> The default queue must be the last queue in the WLM configuration. Any
>   queries that are not routed to other queues run in the default queue.

Anyway, you'll have to live with it, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still confusing because on that same page, it says

-
-

`For example, if you configure four queues, you can allocate memory as follows: 20 percent, 30 percent, 15 percent, 15 percent. The remaining 20 percent is unallocated and managed by the service.`

Comment: that doesn't contradict anything on the documentation

Comment: Maybe it doesn't contradict it directly, but it implies that you can have unallocated memory, whereas elsewhere in the document, it says you have to have to define a default queue.

The difference is that before, when you could have unallocated memory, I thought that maybe the system could temporarily give more resources to different queues if it thought it would improve performance. (Maybe it never did that though, I don't know).

But now, it seems to imply that every queue has a fixed capacity, and that the default queue is only for running queries that don't qualify for other queues